# difference between _default_:* and *:* in VirtualHost Context

Tags: apache, tomcat, virtualhost

I want to know the difference between **"*default*:*"**  and  **"*:*"** in  VirtualHost Context.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
  #...
  ServerName host.example.com
  #...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:*>
  #...
  ServerName host.example.com
  #...
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't know the difference and the porpouse of use.

Thk

Answer (score 1):

There hasn't been a demonstrable difference since at least the 2.0 release. I investigated all of this while deprecating/removing the NameVirtualHost directive before the 2.4 release of httpd.